# You have an error in your SQL syntax - mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Изучаю PHP, сделал небольшую форму, которая должна отправить данные в mySQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO lines (content) VALUES ('test content')";
$conn->query($sql);
```

Пытаюсь попробовать заполнить хотя бы одну колонку, но получаю ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'lines (content) VALUES ('test content')' at line 1

Структура таблицы ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: судя по ошибке - lines есть непонятным элементом... Есть такая таблица?

Comment: @DNS, в базе данных создал две таблицы, lines и songs. В songs пишет отлично, в lines не хочет. `INSERT INTO `lines`(`id`, `song_id`, `line_id`, `language`, `content`, `created`, `user_ip`, `votes`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8])` - так предлагает заполнять ее mySQL.

Comment: @DNS если в базе нет таблицы то ошибка будет совсем другая, как бы

Comment: ошибка пишет от места возникновения. То есть непонятка с `lines`. Попробуйте взять название в кавычки (только ё-кнопка)

Comment: @DNS, cработало! Почему с другой таблицей этого не понадобилось, есть догадки (на будущее)?

Comment: Не знаю, просто поделился опытом. Такое часто бывает. Почему одно можно без кавычек, другое - с, не знаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как это ни удивительно, но lines - это [ключевое слово в Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html), так что его надо заключать в обратные апострофы

```
INSERT INTO `lines` (content) VALUES ('test content')
```

Comment: Спасибо! DNS ответил немного раньше, но вы объяснили причину. Если никто не против, зачту этот ответ.

Comment: Конечно, засчитывайте. Достойный зачета ответ

Comment: Но использование кавычек, по моему опыту, выходит за попадание в ключевые слова. Особенно при управлении пользователями типа `user@localhost` против `'user'@'localhost'`